# Beginner question about looping redundant code

Tags: c++, c++14, juce

I have a quick question about looping some redundant code in a JUCE application I'm playing with.

I have generated some faders and I'm laying them out in a flex box. It seems silly to do the same thing six times (will later be way more than six)

Is there a simple way to loop through this line six times?

```
flexbox.items.add(FlexItem(50, 100, slider1));
flexbox.items.add(FlexItem(50, 100, slider2));
flexbox.items.add(FlexItem(50, 100, slider3));
flexbox.items.add(FlexItem(50, 100, slider4));
flexbox.items.add(FlexItem(50, 100, slider5));
flexbox.items.add(FlexItem(50, 100, slider6));
```

I also have this one that would be great to be able to simply change the number of the slider and iterate...

```
slider1.setSliderStyle(juce::Slider::SliderStyle::LinearVertical);
slider1.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
slider1.setTextBoxStyle(Slider::NoTextBox, true, 0, 0);
addAndMakeVisible(slider1);
```

Apologies if this has been asked before, I can't find something similar enough to it in my searches.

Comment: Use [arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Comment: @PM77-1 Use [the answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

This is what arrays are for. If you had an array of sliders, rather than six separately-named and unrelated objects, then yes you could simply loop over them.

As it is, you *could* create an array of pointers-to-sliders, stick all six inside it then iterate over that.

We don't have enough information to give a concrete solution because you did not post a MCVE.